# Java Evaluate IF statement

Tags: java, if-statement

```
String groupType="local";

        if(groupType==null ||groupType.equals("")||!groupType.equalsIgnoreCase("local")||!groupType.equalsIgnoreCase("global")||!groupType.equalsIgnoreCase("universal")){
              System.out.print("evlauate to true ");

        }
```

Why does this code evaluate to true, !groupType.equalsIgnoreCase("local") should set it to false ,

Comment: and `!groupType.equalsIgnoreCase("global")` should be true

Comment: You combine the conditions with OR. It's enough that one of them is true.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you reduce the condition to

```
if (!groupType.equalsIgnoreCase("local")||!groupType.equalsIgnoreCase("global"))
```

It will always be true, since `groupType` can't be equal to both "local" and "global" at the same time.

You probably want to use `&&` (AND) instead of `||` (OR).

```
if (groupType == null || groupType.equals("") ||
    (!groupType.equalsIgnoreCase("local") && !groupType.equalsIgnoreCase("global") && !groupType.equalsIgnoreCase("universal"))) {
    System.out.print("evaluate to true ");
}
```

Now it will evaluate to `true` if `groupType` is either null or empty or isn't equal to one of the values "local"/"global"/"universal". I'm assuming that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at each of the operands of the `||` operator:

- the string is equal to `null`? False.
- the string is empty? False.
- the string is not equal to "local"? False.
- the string is not equal to "global"? True.
- the string is not equal to "universal"? True.

Two of the conditions evaluate to true. Therefore, the whole if statement evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you wanted this:

```
if(groupType==null ||groupType.equals("")
   ||!(groupType.equalsIgnoreCase("local")
       ||groupType.equalsIgnoreCase("global")
       ||groupType.equalsIgnoreCase("universal")
      )
  )
```

Comment: Offtopic comment: you just edited one of my answers. Which is OK per se; but in your case: bad edit. For example you put _ chars in the method name, which is an absolutely **no go** as really all coding guidelines for java suggest to **not** do that. It is also not required to create an explicit "result" variable when using assertThat! Just wanted to let you know why your edit wont make it!

Comment: **OffToppic** @GhostCat: _"follow the rule, break the rule, be the rule!"_ I and Roy Osherove (author of _The Art of UnitTesting_ ) aggree that Underscores in TestMethod names are the best way to visually separate its 3 parts : **testedMethod_precondition_expectedResult** what was your suggestion to make that obvious?

Comment: The question is: when you are in an environment where 99% of all developers follow the common practices, every *deviation* from those conventions will force your brain to spent extra CPU cycles when looking at such code. Thus I prefer to use "language" that matches with what those 99% are most likely dealing with. And for me, I have no problems writing or reading something like testFooWithBla, testFooWithBlaAndBlub, ...

Comment: And for the record: looking at this answer ( i picked randomly to comment on) ... readability is something you could look into. I think the above is a good example how to never ever put together an if condition.

Comment: **OffTopic** @GhostCat: _"The question is: when you are in an environment where 99% of all developers..."_ do I have to like what millions of flies like? Your argument is readability. Mine (and Roys) is the same. Even people who never used underscores in method names will understand that they separate **parts** rather than **words**. Also I'm not saying or implying that you should use them in production code method names. But maybe we should discuss this somehere else...